# rewrite query to use subquery(s)?

Tags: sql

I'm a real noob with SQL, but could anyone tell me how to make this query use "subquerys" instead?... instead of joining the tables which is what I'm guessing I'm doing now:

```
select Produkt.Namn from Produkt, Kund, InkOrder
where Produkt.ProdId = InkOrder.ProdId 
AND InkOrder.KundId = Kund.KundId
AND InkOrder.Datum = '2011-09-24'
AND Kund.Namn = 'Allstad'
```

Comment: For what reason? You just woke up today morning and your first thought was: "It's a good day to pick a random query and add some subqueries there"?

Comment: Voices in my head told me...no :), just a school assignment I couldnt get past. Thought I might as well post it here before I go to bed

Comment: then add the tag of "homework" to your question, and futures like it.  No problem to help, just let us know up front and help guide you.

Comment: @DRapp `homework` is no longer to be used: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite the query using joins first:

```
SELECT Produkt.Namn
  FROM Produkt
  JOIN InkOrder ON Produkt.ProdId  = InkOrder.ProdId
  JOIN Kund     ON InkOrder.KundId = Kund.KundId
 WHERE InkOrder.Datum = '2011-09-24'
   AND Kund.Namn = 'Allstad'
```

Then we can note that the conditions in the WHERE clause could be pushed down into the ON clauses:

```
SELECT Produkt.Namn
  FROM Produkt
  JOIN InkOrder ON Produkt.ProdId  = InkOrder.ProdId AND InkOrder.Datum = '2011-09-24'
  JOIN Kund     ON InkOrder.KundId = Kund.KundId AND Kund.Namn = 'Allstad'
```

So, if a sub-query was really a good idea (it probably isn't, but there's a decent chance the optimizer will spot that and process it like a join anyway), then we could write:

```
SELECT Produkt.Namn
  FROM Produkt
  JOIN InkOrder ON Produkt.ProdId  = InkOrder.ProdId AND InkOrder.Datum = '2011-09-24'
 WHERE InkOrder.KundId IN (SELECT KundID FROM Kund WHERE Namn = 'Allstad')
```

and then get a second sub-query in with:

```
SELECT Produkt.Namn
  FROM Produkt
 WHERE Produkt.ProdId IN
       (SELECT ProdId
          FROM InkOrder
         WHERE Datum = '2011-09-24'
           AND KundId IN (SELECT KundID FROM Kund WHERE Namn = 'Allstad')
       )
```

OTOH, the versions with the explicit JOIN operations are by far the clearest.  You can write the filter conditions in the ON clause, but it's arguably clearer to write them in the (main) WHERE clause, leaving the optimizer to push the filter conditions down.  It's such an important optimization that it is unlikely that any production-quality DBMS would not do that optimization.